# Get String from SQL function, no entity, kotlin

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, kotlin

Im confused.. 
I need to use Oracle function to retrieve just a single String, No entity.

So i try to use CrudRepository, but that dosent work without Entity?

```
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<Contact, String>{
   @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT schema.get_user(:id) FROM DUAL")
   fun getUser(id: String): String?
}
```

or

```
interface UserRepository : CrudRepository<Contact, String>{
   @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT schema.get_user(:id) AS name, '' AS email FROM DUAL")
   fun getUser(id: String): String?
}
```

where i try to name returning string to fit entity i seem to be forced to use.

Entity Contact is super simple entity with two attributes.

```
@Entity
data class Contact(
    @Id
    val name: String?,
    val email: String?
)
```

**Function will only ever return one string**, but i cant figure how would i insert that as a name.. With this Query i get `ORA-00904: : invalid identifier` most likely because i have no idea how to match identifier returned from function.. (SQLdeveloper gives function name  as column name but the returned string dosent really have ANY column name, since it is calculated...)

I can't do a repository for a `String` either, can i?

**EDIT: trying to clarify what i need:** 
Entity has two attributes, just one comes from the Query including function, other one must be fetch from other side of the world. How do i run this query and return either single string or entity (with email as null) only have gotten array of errors so far, thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Why do you return two columns and want to have one String as result

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Entity has two attributes, just one comes from the Query including function, otherone must be fetch from other side of the world. How do i run this query and return either single string or entity (with email as null) only have gotten array of errors so far, thanks

Comment: But the name is the ID that will not work.